# array under sh shell (not bash)

Tags: linux, shell

A simple question, can I use array under just `sh`, not `bash` `zsh` or any thing else.

`ARRAYNAME=(value1 value2  .... valueN)`
The command above works only in `bash`. Is there **any alternative** in `sh`?
I tried to search such question but not found the answer for pure sh.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's only one "array" in POSIX sh at each stack frame, and that is the current scope's argument list.

You can reset it:

```
set -- "first item" "second item"
```

...append to it:

```
set -- "$@" "new item"
```

...remove things from the front of it:

```
echo "First item is $1"
shift
echo "First item is $1"
```

...and create a new one by jumping into a new function scope:

```
someFunc() {
  echo "The argument list for this function is:" >&2
  printf ' - %s\n' "$@"
}

someFunc argOne argTwo
```

...but because there's only one in scope at a time, it's very limited.

If it **weren't** limited, there would have been no reason for ksh (and later bash and others) to add any other form of arrays!

---

One hack is to abuse strings as if they were arrays, splitting them into function arguments when you need to index into them:

```
s='A|B|C|D' # specify your "array" as a string with a sigil between elements
IFS='|'     # specify separator between elements
set -f      # disable glob expansion, so a * doesn't get replaced with a list of files

getNth()  { shift "$(( $1 + 1 ))"; printf '%s\n' "$1"; }
getLast() { getNth "$(( $(length "$@") - 1 ))" "$@"; }
length()  { echo "$#"; }

length $s   # emits 4
getNth 0 $s # emits A
getNth 1 $s # emits B
getLast $s  # emits D
```

Of course, this means you need to have a reserved sigil character that isn't present in values.

---

As a 3rd-party shell library that operates similarly to the above (encoding "arrays" into strings, and storing and retrieving content in those strings), but with escaping/unescaping support such that no sigil is needed, you might also take a look at https://github.com/makefu/array/blob/master/array. That said, the above code invokes external executables for every lookup -- you'll quickly lose any gain you might have had in shell startup time by going with POSIX sh to the extra runtime overhead of invoking copies of `sed` and `awk` for every operation.

Comment: Also, prepend: `set -- new "$@"`

Comment: Does posix sh (or bash) even create a stack frame for each function call? How would dynamic scoping being possible (and the default) if each function call would have it's own stack frame?

Comment: @hek2mgl, mmm? Same as one has both a heap and a stack in C, your locals are in a stack (in bash or ksh, where one *has* locals), and other variables live outside it. I didn't mean the phrase "stack frame" to be interpreted restrictively, but bash does very much use the term in its own documentation (see `BASH_ARGC` and `BASH_ARGV` definitions f/e; likewise the definition for `FUNCNAME`). Even in POSIX sh, for argument lists a stack is the obvious implementation, and an easy idiom for describing behavior.

Comment: @hek2mgl, ...reading the source to dash, it (in `evalfun` in `eval.c`) uses the C stack to store old values of the parameter list when jumping into a function -- but it's still very much a stack in effect.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the response. I was commenting in the hope to learn, not to be right :) I haven't looking at the C code level yet, I just recently learned about dynamic scoping in the shell when I had to debug an application. I would personally avoid making use of it after reading that code.